# Ag grid get field value inside custom cell renderer Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to get the column field value inside my cell renderer. I can do that through `params.data.code` inside agInit hookup method but that would make the cell renderer non reusable for other components, as field 'code' is not generic.

[In the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#cell-rendering-flow) it says it will use valueGetter(with or wout valueFormatter) instead of field, if provided; but in the renderer `params.value` it's always undefined.

Column definition attemtps:

```
      {
        headerName: "test",
        field: 'code', 
        cellRenderer: CustomCellRendererComponent,
        cellRendererParams: {
          title: "title-for-custom-component",
          parent: this,
        }
      }

      {
        headerName: "test",
        field: 'code', 
        cellRenderer: CustomCellRendererComponent,
        cellRendererParams: {
          title: "title-for-custom-component",
          parent: this,
        },
        valueGetter: (params) => return params.data.code,
      }

     {
        headerName: "test",
        field: 'code', 
        cellRenderer: CustomCellRendererComponent,
        cellRendererParams: {
          title: "title-for-custom-component",
          parent: this,
          value: (params) => {params.data.code}
        },
      }
```

Cell renderer:

```
export class CustomCellRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {

 refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    return false;
  }

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
    //1st try will print undefined
    //2nd try will print undefined
    //3rd try will print (params) => { params.data.code; }
    console.log("valuegetter:"+this.params.value)

    //this one works, but here I'm accessing the 'code' field from the row, so it's not reusable
    console.log("valuegetter:"+this.params.data.code)
    //I am able to access title and parent params as well
   
  }

 }
```

Is it possible to get the field value without accessing row data from within the renderer? Or must I go through params.data to achieve so?

Comment: You'll have to use params.data in the cell renderer.  But you can use an interface to ensure that every params.data WILL have the "code" property

Comment: In ag-grid-react it works as documented. `params.value` is defined

Comment: In your renderer component, you probably need to have `params.value` instead of `this.params.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging and following the data source, `params.value` it is indeed working.

The value for that specific field was explicitly being set to `undefined` somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem like you and I try to write a valueGetter, It's works.

```
 {
      headerName: 'Thao tác',
      headerClass: "header-center",
      cellStyle: { justifyContent: 'center' },
      filter: false,
      sortable: false,
      resizable: false,
      minWidth: 220,
      maxWidth: 220,
      pinned: 'right',
      suppressFiltersToolPanel: true,
      cellRendererFramework: ActionCellComponent,
      valueGetter: (params: ICellRendererParams) => params
    },
```

Angular 14+